# Filewatcher in Powershell not firing events

Tags: powershell

Hopefully this is a quick answer for a powershell expert.

I have a powershell script that is using IO.FileSystemWatcher. When I test my code in the ISE without saving the file the file watcher works. But when the script is saved in another location it will not execute (even in the ISE).

I am assuming there is some execution policy that is blocking it. What do I need to do to get it working? I am an Admin and I need this to run on a server when I get it working.

```
try
{
  Write-Warning "FileSystemWatcher is monitoring $Path"
  
  # create a filesystemwatcher object
  $watcher = New-Object -TypeName IO.FileSystemWatcher -ArgumentList $Path, $FileFilter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $IncludeSubfolders
    NotifyFilter = $AttributeFilter
  }

  # start monitoring manually in a loop:
  do
  {
    # wait for changes for the specified timeout
    # IMPORTANT: while the watcher is active, PowerShell cannot be stopped
    # so it is recommended to use a timeout of 1000ms and repeat the
    # monitoring in a loop. This way, you have the chance to abort the
    # script every second.
    $result = $watcher.WaitForChanged($ChangeTypes, $Timeout)
    # if there was a timeout, continue monitoring:
    if ($result.TimedOut) { continue }
    
    if ($RunVersion -eq "Live")
    {
        ProcessCsv -Change $result
    
    }else
    {
        ProcessCsvTest -Change $result
    }


    # the loop runs forever until you hit CTRL+C    
  } while ($true)
}
catch
{
    write-host "An error occurred"
    Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace
}
finally
{
  # release the watcher and free its memory:
  $watcher.Dispose()
  Write-Warning 'FileSystemWatcher removed.'
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working?  Is there an error?  Have you tried trapping and writing out errors?  Please know "it don't work" is next to impossible to help with when you don't include this info.

Comment: I think you need to set the [`enableraisingevents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.enableraisingevents) to `$True`.

Comment: @iRon, that's actually not necessary when the synchronous `.WaitForChanged()` method is used.

Comment: @Colyn1337 The script ran but the filesystemwatcher piece would not execute when the file was saved on my machine. But it did work when pasting into a new unsaved ISE file and running it. I had my local execution policy with Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted when testing it and it did not work. I have a feeling there was some global policy that was blocking this - after a few hours it worked without any code changes.

Answer (score 4):

An **aside** re **your file-system watcher code**:

The file-system watcher's synchronous **[`.WaitForChanged()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.WaitForChanged) method is convenient, but it has two disadvantages**:

- It can cause you to *miss* events: for instance, if *multiple* files are created virtually *simultaneously*, only *one* event is reported.
- While the method is waiting, PowerShell will not respond to <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, which necessitates the periodic-timeout workaround in your code.

A **better alternative** that avoids these problems is to use **[`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent)** to register for file-system change events and then **[`Wait-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-event)** to synchronously receive events in a loop.

The following simplified code demonstrates this approach; waits for `Created` events and prints out event details as each event is received:

```
# Sample directory path and file-name pattern to monitor.
$path = "C:\somed\dir" 
$fileFilter = '*'
  
Write-Verbose -vb "FileSystemWatcher is monitoring $path...."

try {
  
  # Create the file-system watcher instance.
  $watcher = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -ArgumentList $path, $fileFilter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    # NotifyFilter = ... # What attributes to monitor; by default: LastWrite, FileName, and DirectoryName - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.notifyfilters
  }

  # Register for (subscribe to) creation events:
  # Determine a unique event-source ID...
  [string] $sourceId = New-Guid
  # ... and register for the watcher's `Created` event with it.
  Register-ObjectEvent $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier $sourceId

  # Run indefinitely; use Ctrl-C to exit.
  while ($true) {

    # Wait (indefinitely) in blocking fashion for the next pending event.
    # Ctrl-C *does* work while waiting.
    $event = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier $sourceId
    # The event must be manually removed from the queue.
    $event | Remove-Event
    
    # $event is an object of type [System.Management.Automation.PSEventArgs], 
    # $event.SourceArgs contains the event argument as an [object[]] array.
    # The 2nd event argument received contains the event details:
    # an object with .ChangeType, .FullPath and .Name properties.
    $eventDetails = $event.SourceArgs[1]
    
    # !! Due to an apparent bug up to at least PS 7.2,
    # !! outputting a non-primitive object whose type does NOT
    # !! have associated formatting data BLOCKS PIPELINE INPUT,
    # !! UNLESS an object WITH formatting data was output first (e.g., Get-Item /)
    # !! WORKAROUND for this demo: Use Out-Host
    $eventDetails | Out-Host

  }
}
finally {
  Write-Verbose -vb 'Cleaning up...'
  # Clean up:
  # Unregister the event subscription.
  Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $sourceId
  # Dispose of the watcher.
  $watcher.Dispose() 
}
```

Comment: I like your point with the synchronous task. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

This just started working again after no code or policy changes on my end. I believe our networking team may have added some blocking of scripts that I was not able to see.